# Highcharts ajax implementation not loading object inside success

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I just started working with Highcharts and am trying to load categories from API data I have and I can't seem to call my options object that I set before the request

```
       var categories = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: '',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result, function () {
                    $.each(this.Values, function (i) {
                        var date = this.Date.substr(0, 4);
                        //console.log(date);
                        //console.log(this.Value);
                        categories[i] = this.Value
                        //console.log(categories);
                        //options.xAxis.categories.push(this.Value);
                    });
                });
                console.log(options.xAxis.categories);
            }
        });
```

Here is the object

```
    var url = sApiURL + '/api/';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //testing for Housing_Prices
        var chart;
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'Housing_Prices',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Mean/Median prices for homes over the years'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Price'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 80,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                shadow: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return "$600,000 in " + this.key;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Existing Home Median Price',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

            }, {
                name: 'Existing Condo Median Price',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

            }, {
                name: 'Existing Single Family Median Price',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Starter Home Median Price',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

            },
            {
                name: 'Existing Home Mean Price',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]
            },
            {
                name: 'Existing Condo Mean Price',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 400.3, 51.2]
            },
            {
                name: 'Existing Single Family Mean Price',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 200.2]
            }]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` variable is outside of the DOM-ready scope, but `options` is not so it is not visible in whatever scope your XHR gets called.

```
var url = sApiURL + '/api/', options;

$(document).ready(function () {
    //testing for Housing_Prices
    var chart;
    options = {
```